# Не могу написать код в новом View Controller

Tags: swift

В Storyboard создал новый View Controller, но не могу написать в нем код. Даже TextField не соединить с Assistance. Помогите с проблемой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сториборде нужно выбрать новый добавленный экран и указать в инспекторе класс вьюконтроллера (если его еще нет, то его тоже нужно создать), который будет связан с этим экраном.

[image: inspectors]